# Workaround to make Contact lookup field searchable

Tags: lookup

I believe the lookup fields are not searchable via Global search..

In the Case object we have contact as a look up field. When we search for a contact name in the global search it returns with 0 cases even though there are some cases associated with that Contact..I believe this is because the contact field is look up field in Case object and it is not searchable...

But we are looking for a workaround for this issue. Has anyone had similar issue and the business wants us to retrieve cases when they search by contact...

Just throwing it out in case if anyone else had this challenge and implemented any workarounds for this issue..

Answer (score 6):

You can create a text field where you can copy name of the contact using trigger or workflow with field update and it will be searchable by contact name. We had the same issue, but with different objects and we resolved it this way.